# Azure B2C implicit flow: acquire new access token witout the use of an iFrame

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, implicit-flow

In the Azure B2C documentation you have this information about silently acquiring new access tokens when the previous one expired.

> ID tokens and access tokens both expire after a short period of time.
>   Your app must be prepared to refresh these tokens periodically. To
>   refresh either type of token, perform the same hidden iframe request
>   we used in an earlier example, by using the prompt=none parameter to
>   control Azure AD steps. To receive a new id_token value, be sure to
>   use response_type=id_token and scope=openid, and a nonce parameter.

Is there a way to do this without an iFrame?

Comment: Please let us know which library you are using MSAL or ADAL?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a full redirect by calling acquireTokenReditect() with MSAL. There is no other option in a javascript app. This of course is not going to be a good UX as you’d need to do it every time the api resource changes or scope changes.